# Are you legally obliged to show the registered symbol with a logo?

Tags: copyright, trademark

If an external company's logo includes a registered symbol, are you obligated to reproduce it (in a link to their website, for example) along with this symbol? What if the usage guidelines dictate the use of (R) -- can you omit it?

Answer (score 1):

We should do so the first time the registered mark is used on any given webpage or article and such and we can then proceed with "clean hands" omitting the registration symbol during the rest of the article or whatever.

It shows good faith not to infringe noting our corrupt courts now allow lawyers to sue a ham sandwich as it is said so do not give bottom feeding lawyers any opportunity to claim infringement and by all means it goes without saying that we should not infringe. Period. We can also include a disclaimer somewhere visible to the general public that will see the use of the 3rd party's registered mark.

If the mark is declared with TM that declaration carries no legal recourse for protection although the same is not true of the use of the SM designation.

Keep your hands clean.